# Add submenu in Caldera form plugin in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, submenu

I want to add a submenu in caldera form plugin but I can't find how to do this. The core file of plugin is shown below

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: Caldera Forms
 Plugin URI: https://CalderaForms.com
 Description: Easy to use, grid based responsive form builder for creating simple to complex forms.
 Author: CalderaWP
 Version: 1.4.7
 Author URI: http://CalderaLabs.org
 Text Domain: caldera-forms
 GitHub Plugin URI: https://github.com/CalderaWP/Caldera-Forms/
 GitHub Branch:     1.4.x
*/


// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

define('CFCORE_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
define('CFCORE_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
define('CFCORE_VER', '1.4.6.7');
define('CFCORE_EXTEND_URL', 'https://api.calderaforms.com/1.0/');
define('CFCORE_BASENAME', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ));

/**
* Caldera Forms DB version
*
* @since 1.3.4
*
* PLEASE keep this an integer
*/
define( 'CF_DB', 4 );

// init internals of CF
include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/core.php'; // needs the core at the very least before plugins loaded
add_action( 'init', array( 'Caldera_Forms', 'init_cf_internal' ) );
// table builder
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Caldera_Forms', 'activate_caldera_forms' ) );

// load system
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'caldera_forms_load', 0 );
function caldera_forms_load(){

    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/autoloader.php';
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/widget.php';
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_DB', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/db' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_Entry', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/entry' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_Email', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/email' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_Admin', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/admin' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_Render', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/render' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_CSV', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/csv' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_Processor_Interface', CFCORE_PATH . 'processors/classes/interfaces' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_API', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/api' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_Field', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/field' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_Magic', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes/magic' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms_Processor', CFCORE_PATH . 'processors/classes' );

    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::add_root( 'Caldera_Forms', CFCORE_PATH . 'classes' );
    Caldera_Forms_Autoloader::register();

    // includes
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'includes/ajax.php';
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'includes/field_processors.php';
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'includes/custom_field_class.php';
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'includes/filter_addon_plugins.php';
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'includes/compat.php';
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'processors/functions.php';
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'includes/functions.php';

    /**
     * Runs after all of the includes and autoload setup is done in Caldera Forms core
     *
     * @since 1.3.5.3
     */
    do_action( 'caldera_forms_includes_complete' );

}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Caldera_Forms', 'get_instance' ) );
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Caldera_Forms_Tracking', 'get_instance' ) );


// Admin & Admin Ajax stuff.
if ( is_admin() || defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Caldera_Forms_Admin', 'get_instance' ) );
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Caldera_Forms_Support', 'get_instance' ) );
    include_once CFCORE_PATH . 'includes/plugin-page-banner.php';
}
```

I want to add the submenu to show the form entries submitted by user for admin use only.

Comment: I could easily spend my life explaining that [urgent begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) is not a good way to address volunteers. Please do not add that to any of your questions, anywhere on the internet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sub menu item for showing entries -- with an option to choose which users roles can see it -- from the Form Settings tab in the form editor.

See: https://calderaforms.com/doc/configure-form-settings/